# ray restore checkpoint in rllib

Tags: ray

Ray saves a bunch of checkpoints during a call of `agent.train()`. How do I know which one is the checkpoint with the best agent to load?
Is there any function like `tune-analysis-output.get_best_checkpoint(path, mode="max")` to explore different loading possibilities over the checkpoints?

Comment: rllib has no way to 'benchmark' a checkpoint so there is no way to know (right now) which checkpoint 'is best'. However, I would also like a method for this, or even a `agent.restore_last_checkpoint()` would already be a great addition but likely much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in https://discuss.ray.io/t/ray-restore-checkpoint-in-rllib/3186/2 you can use:

```
analysis = tune.Analysis(experiment_path)  # can also be the result of `tune.run()`

trial_logdir = analysis.get_best_logdir(metric="metric", mode="max")  # Can also just specify trial dir directly

checkpoints = analysis.get_trial_checkpoints_paths(trial_logdir)  # Returns tuples of (logdir, metric)
best_checkpoint = analysis.get_best_checkpoint(trial_logdir, metric="metric", mode="max")
```

See https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/api_docs/analysis.html#id1

Answer (score 0):

```
analysis = tune.run( 
    "A2C", 
    name = model_name,
    config = config, 
    ...
    checkpoint_freq = 5,
    checkpoint_at_end = True,
    restore = best_checkpoint 
    )



trial_logdir = analysis.get_best_logdir(metric="episode_reward_mean", mode="max")  
best_checkpoint = analysis.get_best_checkpoint(trial_logdir, metric="episode_reward_mean", mode="max")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not work for me since what you mentioned here is for `tune`, not for `agent.train()`.